# QuantLib Installation using Homebrew on Mac with M1 chip

Tags: c++, apple-m1, quantlib

I'm quite new to Mac system and trying to use Homebrew to install QuantLib for a c++ coursework on XCode. I have installed boost and followed the steps on the [website](https://www.quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml), but met a problem at the step of entering this into the terminal:

```
./configure --with-boost-include=/usr/local/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --prefix=/usr/local/ \
            CXXFLAGS='-O2 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9' \
            LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
```

Since it is m1 chip, the default path of Homebrew has changed to /opt/homebrew/ and so has the location of boost, so I've changed it to

```
./configure --with-boost-include=/opt/homebrew/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/ --prefix=/opt/homebrew/ \
            CXXFLAGS='-O2 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=11.4' \
            LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=11.4'
```

But it still doesn't work and shows:

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: opt/homebrew/
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) awk
checking for opt/homebrew/-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for opt/homebrew/-g++... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-c++... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-gpp... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-aCC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-CC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-cxx... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-cc++... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-cl.exe... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-FCC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-KCC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-RCC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-xlC_r... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-xlC... no
checking for opt/homebrew/-clang++... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `opt/homebrew/': machine `opt/homebrew/-unknown' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config/config.sub opt/homebrew/ failed
```

How should I change the prefix? Any suggestion would be very welcome!

Comment: `--with-boost-lib=/opt/homebre/lib/` is spelled wrong
`--prefix=/opt/homebrew` is the output path so it should stay the same

Comment: you can also run `cat config.log`  to look at the configure log

Comment: Sorry I made a typo here. Thanks for your advice! I'll try!